# ERROR No module named 'flask' on IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-idle, python-3.6

I've a problem with my `flask` install on Mac OSX 10.12, Python 3.6.1 and `pip` installed with:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

I installed `Flask` with

```
sudo pip install Flask
```

But when I launch my code with IDLE (the test code on the flask website) this message appeared:

```
===== RESTART: /Users/logan/Documents/_Prog & Dev/_Python3/Flask_test.py =====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/logan/Documents/_Prog & Dev/_Python3/Flask_test.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: I believe OSX comes with Python 2.7 installed.  A possible problem is that you installed flask for 2.7 and not 3.6.  There have been multiple previous question where this was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `from flask import Flask` rather than`from Flask import Flask`.

In this case, "flask" is the name of this module and "Flask" is a class name.

Update: I agree with [@Terry Jan Reedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722804/terry-jan-reedy)'s comments that your module installation may not corresbond with your Python.
You may use `$ python --version` to see which version of python your system bundled with, which may be also the destination `$ sudo pip install Flask` installed. If your system got Python 2.7, you may use `pip3` to install flask in Python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks, but i've the same problem... i edit my post by the way

Comment: In fact my system have Python 2.7 already installed so i try with pip3 and this work correctly !
Thanks for your help !

I learn with python 2.7 before i've just upgrade to 3.6 so i don't know everything...